# REST webervice running a QSHELL script

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg, clp, qshell

I have a REST web service running an RPG program, as I need to encrypt some data using Openssl I have built a shell script that receives the data via ENV vars and sends out the data in data areas.

Rest_RPG calls a CLP that runs the qsh script, and retrieves the data from the data area.
If I run the cl interactively it works perfectly and it retrieves the data from the data area but when called from the REST web service it doesn't retrieve anything, I have gave authority to QTMHHTTP and QTMHHTP1 to QGPL and no luck, any ideas?

script:
print -nr $PASS | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -K $KEY_HEX -nosalt -base64 | datarea -wl $DTAPASS

CLP:
CRTDTAARA DTAARA(QGPL/DTAPASS) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(512) AUT(*ALL)
ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(PASS) VALUE(&PPASS) CCSID(*JOB) REPLACE(*YES)
qsh('/tmp/script.sh')
RTVDTAARA DTAARAQGPL/DTAPASS) RTNVAR(&ENC_PASS)

Answer (score 0):

seems issue is with relative path name (QGPL library) and -wl combination.
Please try creating dataarea in another library which is part of library list of job or use datarea -w option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried other libraries, gave up, I'm using the IBM Cryptographic APIs now.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/catcrypt.htm?fbclid=IwAR0-BGP-6wdBQPMXP3lp-EPSARpfcIcdCuEE5RzcGYBIdbnVFCno0qVjyBU

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).